# writing to specified position in appending mode

Tags: python, file, append

in python I found that:

```
a=open('x', 'a+')
a.write('3333')
a.seek(2)       # move there pointer
assert a.tell() == 2  # and it works
a.write('11')   # and doesnt work
a.close()
```

gives `333311` in x file, but we did second write with 2 bytes offset, not 4,
so seek doesn't work there for writing despite file-stream pointer is changed.

===> My question: is it a programming standard for more popular languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation at http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html:

> Note that if the file is opened for appending (mode 'a' or 'a+'), any seek() operations will be undone at the next write.

Open the file in `'r+'` mode, which means "read and write".

Answer (score 1):

A file in append mode always appends the `write()`s to the end of the file, as you can see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/open.html):

> O_APPEND
>
> If set, the file offset will be set to the end of the file prior to each write.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html).  It basically lets you edit a file in place.
From the docs:

```
import mmap

# write a simple example file
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write("Hello Python!\n")

with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    # read content via standard file methods
    print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello Python!"
    # read content via slice notation
    print mm[:5]  # prints "Hello"
    # update content using slice notation;
    # note that new content must have same size
    mm[6:] = " world!\n"
    # ... and read again using standard file methods
    mm.seek(0)
    print mm.readline()  # prints "Hello  world!"
    # close the map
    mm.close()
```